# A user with the account name DOMAIN\user could not be found

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, web-services, soap, domain

The query cannot be run for the following `DataObject: GetUserProfileByName`
InfoPath cannot run the specified query.
The SOAP response indicates that an error has occurred:

> A user with the account name `camel\username` could not be found. An error was encountered while retrieving the user profile.

On the InfoPath 2010 preview or in the published site SharePoint 2010 has the same error.

Infopath security level is set to domain but still the same error.

SOAP address is `http://qaserver:8000/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx`

Comment: is your SharePoint web application using Claim based authentication?

Comment: I have windows authentication. till now, the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1):

> InfoPath Form Services does not support claims based authentication
>   (that's what MS Support told us, when we faced a similar issue with
>   `Nintex Workflow.asmx` about a month back).
>
> If you look in the IIS logs you will see that the calls to the
>   `UserProfileService.asmx` are getting made as `nt authority\anonymous
>   user` instead of the currently logged in user. This happens because
>   FormServer when making the call to the WS is able to use only Basic or
>   Digest mode for passing credentials.
>
> You can fix the issue temperorily by using the udcx:Authentication tag
>   of the udcx file, either by speciying a hard coded user name and
>   password or setting it up to use Secure store service. This fix works
>   because the GetProfileByName method does not require the the currently
>   logged in user to be imperonated when making the call.
>
> But sooner or later you would come across a scenario in which you need
>   to make a call to a Web Service that requires that the call be made
>   using the logged in user's credentials (for eg:
>   `GetRunningWorkflowTasksForCurrentUser` method in Nintex
>   Workflow.asmx), which would fail if you are using InfoPath Form
>   Services in a Claims based environment
>
> **Important:**
>
> The SharePoint application and code described in this article will not
>   work if SharePoint is configured for forms-based authentication. To
>   work correctly, the web application that hosts this SharePoint
>   application **must be configured to use classic-mode authentication**.
>   For more information about configuring SharePoint authentication, see
>   Plan authentication methods (SharePoint Server 2010)".

Comment: yes its in classic mode authentication . and userprofilebyname isnt working.
how do i hard code udcx file user name and password?